# How to display data in field type with dropdown multi select checkbox?

Tags: plugin-development, templating

I'm able to get data using API but when I use checkboxField then it only display the blank checkbox without value. In Model,

```
    if($result){
        if (isset($result->error)) die($result->error_message);
        //convert json data to array
        $arr = json_decode($result, true);

        //Get project array from API
        $json = $arr['projects'];

        foreach ($json as $i => $v){

            return array_merge(parent::defineAttributes(), array(
                'someField'     => array(AttributeType::String, 'default' => $v['name']),
            ));
        }
```

And my template,

```
{% import "_includes/forms" as forms %}

{{ forms.checkboxField({
id: id ~ 'someField',
class:'nicetext',
name: name ~ '[someField]',
value: values.someField,
checked: value,
errors: values.getErrors('someField'),
required: false,}) }}
```

Need some help. TIA!

Answer (score 1):

A checkbox field is just a checkbox, usually checkboxes don't have several values beside true/false or checked/unchecked, Are you sure you don't want to use a `select` or `multiselect`

```
{{ forms.selectField({
    label: "Some Label"|t,
    id: id ~ 'someField',
    name: name ~ '[someField]',
    options: options, //<-- array [label => X, value => y]
    value: values.someField // <-- not sure what this should be.. usually you want to pass an id
}) }}
```

However - your PHP actually doesn't make much sense. Not sure what your goal is with that code

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I'm having problem with display strings in the template(select or checkbox). I updated the code $add=array();
            foreach ($json as $v){
                $add[]= array(
                    'someField'     => array(AttributeType::String, 'default' => $v['name']),
                );
            }

            echo '<pre>'.print_r($add,1).'</pre>';
            return array_merge(parent::defineAttributes(), $add);



        }

Comment: As I said, that makes no sense at all. Your options must be an array with a format like `[ [label => options 1, value = 1], [label => option 2, value 2]]`. Merging arrays in loops is a really bad idea to begin with

Answer (score -1):

**Solution:**
After did some research in plugin development it worked for me, twig doesn't seem to accept php array so I pass string first and than explode the string with the returned value. Then in template, for checkbox(need to make different checkbox name to make boxes clickable),

```
{% for check in options %}
{{ forms.checkboxField({
    id: id ~ 'someField',
    class: 'nicetext',
    name: name ~ '[someField]',
    value: check,
    errors: values.getErrors('someField'),
    required: false,
    label: check
}) }}{% endfor %}
```

and in model,

```
$result = array();
foreach ($json as $key => $value){
    $result[] = $value['name'];
}
$projects = implode(",",$result);

return  array('someField' => array(AttributeType::Enum, 'default' => $projects),
);
```

Comment: **twig doesn't allow php array** -> of course it does

Comment: Is it? directly from model?

Comment: It doesn't matter where it comes from, you can proceed every array in Twig and can create new arrays as well. I guess you just use it wrong. Since your `someField` attribute especially the `default` doesn't seem to be used correctly

Comment: I'm in learning phase, you may be right ,  however, for me  Twig does not seem to accept it if I return a PHP array. so I use implode explode to make things. Thank you very much for your guidance, anyway. :)